# What can be a good cron expression for every trading hour in China stock market?

Tags: cron

China stocks only trades on weekdays, 9:30 - 11:30, then 13:00 - 15:00.

I want to use one cron expression to pick out the following time spots:  9:30, 10:30, 11:30, 13:00, 14:00, 15:00. Basically every hour in the actual trading window.

Is it possible at all?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in python using the [apscheduler](https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/triggers/cron.html) with 2 lines to define the morning and afternoon sessions.

```
    from apscheduler.schedulers.blocking import BlockingScheduler

    def fn():
        print("Hello, world")

    def fn2():
        print("Hello, world2")

    scheduler = BlockingScheduler()

    scheduler.add_job(fn, trigger='cron', day_of_week='mon-fri', hour='9-11', minute=30, second=0)
    scheduler.add_job(fn2, trigger='cron', day_of_week='mon-fri', hour='13-15', minute=0, second=0)

    scheduler.start()
```